# Not getting the inserted data in database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, android-volley

I am getting the data when I try to insert from my phone or IP, But when my friends are trying to add data the data is not inserting in my created database. Why is it happening? I have inserted the IP of mine, and when I insert data from the same IP I get the data in my database. But when others try to add data from their phone or other IP, it is not appearing in the database. Please give some solution how to solve it.
Here is my API code

```
public class Api {
private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://192.168.0.106/DataApi/v1/Api.php?apicall=";
public static final String URL_CREATE_DATA = ROOT_URL + "createdata";
public static final String URL_READ_DATA = ROOT_URL + "getdata";
public static final String URL_UPDATE_DATA = ROOT_URL + "updatedata";
public static final String URL_DELETE_DATA = ROOT_URL + "deletedata&id=";
```

}

Comment: add your `insert` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are using to access the database is a local address. It is not accessible from external IPs.

To make the database globally accessible, you will need to put your external IP address (or domain name) in the code and ensure that the database server is reachable from the outside.